# Angular 4 no Provider for Service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am trying to create an angular app, and trying to use a service in a component,

**My Service :DetailsTabAPiService**

```
@Injectable()
export class DetailsTabAPiService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    private _url: string = AppSettings.URI + "/api/maintenance/Countries";

    fetchCountry(): Observable<ICountries> {
        console.log('contry 3');

        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }


    handleErrors(error: any, caught: Observable<any[]>): Observable<ICountries[]> {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error') as Observable<ICountries[]>;
    }

}
```

**My Controller : DetailTabsComponent**

```
import { MaintPlantApiService } from '../../services/plants-api.service';
import { MaintProgramApiService } from '../../services/programs-api.service';
import { DetailsTabAPiService } from '../../services/detailstab-api.service';
import { IPlants } from '../../models/plants.model';
import { ICountries } from '../../models/Countries.model';
@Component({
    selector: 'ppa-detailtabs',
    templateUrl: './detailtabs.Component.html',
    providers: [MaintProgramApiService, MaintPlantApiService, DetailsTabAPiService],
    styleUrls: ['./tabs.css'],

})

export class DetailTabsComponent {

    @Input() myplantid: number = 0;
    plant: IPlants;
    country: ICountries;
    isSuccess: boolean = false;
    _plantId: number = 0;
    public allowCustom: boolean = true;
    public allCountries = [];
    constructor(private zone: NgZone, private _router: Router, private DetailsApiServ: DetailsTabAPiService, private ProgramsApiSvrc: MaintProgramApiService,
        private plantApiSrv: MaintPlantApiService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('contry 1');
        this.fetchCountryList();

        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            //alert('params received: ' + params['Id']);
            let plantId = params['Id'];
            this.plantApiSrv.getDataById(plantId)
                .subscribe((callbackData) => {
                    this.plant = callbackData;
                });
        });

    }
    ModifyPlantDetails(_data: IPlants): void {

        this.plantApiSrv.update(_data.Id, _data)
            //.subscribe(result => this.plant = result, error => this.isSuccess = false);
            .subscribe(result => {
            this.plant = result; this.isSuccess = true;
            },
            error => { this.isSuccess = false });   

    }


    fetchCountryList(): void {
        console.log('contry 2');

        this.DetailsApiServ.fetchCountry()
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.country = result;
                console.log(this.country);
            },
            error => { this.isSuccess = false });  
    }
}

As per the documentation, I am supped to put the service on the provider list, which I have done, but still while using it gives me the error.
```

I am supposed to get a list of countries from the service. So I have imported the service, then put in the constructor, and then trying to use it.

> But despite doing everything according to the documentation, it's
>   giving me the error "no Provider for Service" even though I am
>   included the service in my providers.

As per my understanding, these should be the steps to get this thing working. But somehow it's not working. Please help. I am sure I am missing something here. But I am not sure What.

Comment: Have you tried adding those services on the providers array at your app main module - **app.module.ts**?

Comment: What's the error shown in the console? Can you update the question with that?

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure to add all needed imports - usually, IDE should take care of it automatically.
2. Check carefully all the paths of services - pay attention to dots, if IDE hasn't done it automatically.
3. Try to push your services to `app.module.ts` instead of adding it to components providers, exactly here: `providers: [AddYourServicesHere]`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import `{ ServiceName }  from " ./WhereverServiceIs" ;`

and make sure you also have your `Providers Array` in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered same error with absolute path in import. Should change

```
import { ExcelExportLogService } from 'app/admin/excel-export-logs/excel-export-log.service';
```

to

```
import { ExcelExportLogService } from './excel-export-log.service';
```

Misleading error message